# Specifying multiple NameVirtualHosts in a VirtualHost configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, configuration

My server is running Apache2 and the configuration contains several NameVirtualHost settings.

```
# Example
NameVirtualHost aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:80
NameVirtualHost xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq:80
NameVirtualHost [aaaa:ssss:dddd:ffff:gggg:hhhh]:80
```

There are Listen settings for all of them.

At this moment in time I am keeping track of two or more `<VirtualHost foo:80>` for each site because I want to be able to control which sites can be accessed through specific IP addresses. One of the reasons for doing it this way is ownership of the IP addresses the sites are being served on.

Question: Is it possible to create a "bundle" NameVirtualHost which contains more than 1 NameVirtualHost but not all NameVirtualHosts at once? The idea and reason for asking this question is that if I can bundle multiple NameVirtualHosts into one, then I would not have to administer multiple `<VirtualHost foo:80>` configuration sets for each site.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just a matter of having multiple domains in `ServerAlias` directive.

You could have one definition:

```
<VirtualHost aaa.bb.ccc.d:80>
      ServerName primary.domain.tld
      ServerAlias another.domain.tld *.example.org whatever.bla.ble
      #... other confs
      VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

This way you can have only one definition, but several domains being served with just one vhost definition.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, but thank you for your answer. I already am using aliases, but the question is about making sure that services are served on the correct IP addresses using 1 VirtualHost, not making sure that one VirtualHost is serving several url/domains/hostnames (Not sure what to call it).

Comment: To make sure what IP serves which content, just place separate logfiles within each virtualhost, and you'll have your answers in the log.